# deserialize message received from message queue

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, json.net, msmq

i am trying to deseriliaze a json message coming from MSMQ, but getting exception while parsing.

i am doing like this:

```
var transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
                transaction.Begin();
                Console.WriteLine("Listening For Message Now...");
                var message = queue.Receive(transaction);
                var reader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream,Encoding.Default);

                var jsonMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var emailMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageType>(jsonMessage);

 The Exception:
................
 Json Parser Exception Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0

The Message Coming from MSMQ with control characters:
 .................................
```

[image]

i think this expection is generic expection that comes while parsing.

What is the proper way of receiving the message from the queue?

Would be nice to get some meaningful examples:)

Comment: What exception? Also what is `formattedString`?

Comment: i have added the expection, i was trying to remove some control characters which was assigned to formattedstring variable, sorry should have pasted the original code

Comment: I wonder if `jsonMessage` actually contains JSON (note I am not familiar with msmq) - any chance you could post the contents of `jsonMessage` (or the first part of it, anyway)?

Comment: i have added the message note that the contents are altered because they have sensitive info

Comment: how are you sending it TO the MSMQ?

Comment: @Bravo11 that isn't JSON, looks more like a `BinaryFormatter` created that.

Comment: ya it looks to me like that and i tried using binaryFormatter to parse it and even didn't work

Comment: Instead of using a stream, have you tried accessing the `Body` property directly to deserialize the object?  e.g., `object payload = message.Body;`

Comment: ya i have tried and did try to deserialize  as binaryformatter and it said its not a valid binary format message

Comment: In order to take a message out of the queue you need to use the same formatter/encoding that was used to put the message into the queue.  So I would start there-- look at the code that was used to put the message into the queue.  What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

A formatter must be set before and after. Here's what I mean:

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\<YourQueue>");

using (MessageQueueTransaction mqt = new MessageQueueTransaction())
        {
            mqt.Begin();
            message = new Message();                    
            message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });
            message.Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<YourJsonObject>);
            mq.Send(message, mqt);
            mqt.Commit();
        }
```

Then you read the message like this:

```
transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();    

using (MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(<YourQueue>)
{
    transaction.Begin();
    mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });
    Message m = mq.Receive(100, transaction);
    YourObjectType o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(m.Body.ToString());
}

transaction.Commit();
```